# How to do basic authentication on a php CLI

Tags: php, basic-authentication

I have a php script on my server which needs to be run by crun. The domain is protected via basic authentication.

```
The command: sudo /usr/bin/php -auth=user:mypass /home/www/app_cron/example.php
```

returns: "not authorized"

due to this code:

```
if ($settings['auth']['passw'] == true){
    $settings['auth']['users']  = array_keys($settings['auth']['passw']);
    $validated = (in_array($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $settings['auth']['users'])) && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == $settings['auth']['passw'][$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']]);
    if (!$validated) {
      header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="'.$system['page']['name'].'"');
      header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
      die ("Not authorized");
    }
}
```

This is a pretty old application and I do not want to mess around much

How can I pass parameters to php via CLI in order to authenticate?

Comment: How does this file implement the authentication?

Comment: apache is configured to protect the site via basic auth. I am surprised that this also counts for a php script that is called over CLI. The file itself does not have any auth code build in.

Comment: A web server has nothing to do with running programs on CLI. The message is coming from `sudo` or your PHP script.

Comment: That's odd. You are executing the file locally. Maybe your script is calling some other page via `curl` or something and then send you this information.

Comment: Found it! $validated = (in_array($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $settings['auth']['users'])) && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == $settings['auth']['passw'][$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']]); How do I pass the credentials on CLI?

Comment: Why does it need authentication if it's meant to be run by cron? You can just move it out of www. Or does it need to be available on the web too?

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Simple solution would be to check the value of `PHP_SAPI`.

Comment: You are right, the file should rather be outside of www. However this app is pretty old and includes other scripts from the project, all within a git repo pushed to www. So I would rather like to leave it as it is and just find a way to pass the known credentials via command line. The protection is there as it is on a staging environment.